# How to obscure classes in a C++ dll?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop, dll, reference

1. I have a C++ class `Alice` that must be exported from a dll. It has references to objects of other custom classes like `Bob`.
2. When I use my dll in another exe project I don't want and **don't need** to know about `Bob` (even if the reference is public).
3. I thought of making something like `HANDLE` in WinApi out of Bob's objects (like IntPtr in C#).

**Reasons:** I need to include `Alice.h` in my exe project to be able to use Alice right ? So I want to expose only 1 header file and not `Bob.h` and `Chellsie.h` and `Detlef.h` and ...

---

**How can I achieve this ?**
Is `HANDLE` a good idea ? Or can I avoid my problem below in a different way ?

---

**Code:**

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Alice
{
public:
    Bob bob;
    Chellsie chellsie;
    Detlef detlef;
};

class __declspec(dllexport) Alice
{
public:
    HANDLE bob;
    HANDLE chellsie;
    HANDLE detlef;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure Alice needs Bob, Bob is an integral part of Alice. It's composition. If you held a pointer to a "Bob", you'd be able to use a forward declaration, but as-is now, a full definition of Bob is required:

```
#include "Bob.h" // required, Bob must be known

class __declspec(dllexport) Alice
{
public:
    Bob bob;
    Chellsie chellsie;
    Detlef detlef;
};
```

vs

```
class Bob; // declaration is enough

class __declspec(dllexport) Alice
{
public:
    Bob* bob;
    Chellsie chellsie;
    Detlef detlef;
};
```

Comment: Will the dll build if I have only one `#include "Bob.h"` in my `Bob.cpp` ? (for now I've got errors to fix, replacing dots with `->`) My main cpp file is `Alice.cpp` and it contains the `DllMain`.